# « D'une importance particulière est … » : quelle formulation est meilleure ?

Tags: science, style-de-rédaction

> Le comportement des nouvelles solutions proches du point d'application des charges, où il existe des singularités et des discontinuités pathologiques dans les solutions classiques, est d'une importance particulière.
>
> D'une importance particulière est le comportement des nouvelles solutions proches du point d'application des charges où il existe des singularités et des discontinuités pathologiques dans les solutions classiques.

Quelle formulation plus adéquate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La deuxième phrase est interminable et l'inversion rend pénible sa lecture.

La première est donc la meilleure. J'y ajouterais l'adverbe *là* pour bien distinguer la proposition intermédiaire :

> Le comportement des nouvelles solutions proches du point d'application des charges, **là** où il existe des singularités et des discontinuités pathologiques dans les solutions classiques, est d'une importance particulière.

Il me semble aussi que le début de la phrase pourrait être :

> Le comportement des nouvelles solutions **à proximité** du point d'application des charges,...

Si l'on souhaite vraiment insister sur l'*importance particulière*, on peut aussi découper la phrase ainsi :

> Une comportement est d'une importance toute particulière. Il s'agit de celui des nouvelles solutions à proximité du point d'application des charges, là où il existe des singularités et des discontinuités avec les solutions classiques.

Comment: L'utilisation de "là " dans  la  deuxième phase la rend beaucoup moins lourde et tout à  fait  correcte .

Comment: @Damien Elle est en effet aussi améliorée par l'ajout du *là*, mais, à mon avis, ne rattrape pas pour autant la première.

Answer (score 4):

La première version est à mes yeux, la plus adéquate:

> Le comportement des nouvelles solutions proches du point d'application des charges, où il existe des singularités et des discontinuités pathologiques dans les solutions classiques, est d'une importance particulière.

L'ensemble *"D'une importance particulière est"* ne sonnant pas correcte.

Answer (score 2):

Les deux formulations sont correctes et contrairement à ce que peuvent affirmer certains, comme user Ced par exemple, ne devrait pas être associé à l'inversion d'effet de lourdeur ou de gaucherie (mais ces notions sont assez subjectives), plus précisément je n'en ressent aucune ; cette inversion est assez souvent utilisée. Présenter le prédicat en tête de phrase focalise l'intérêt sur celui-ci et  souligne ainsi une préoccupation  essentielle. Comme la phrase est assez longue, si on le place à la fin il est loin du noyau du syntagme (comportement), le syntagme étant « Le comportement des nouvelles solutions proches du point d'application des charges, où il existe des singularités et des discontinuités pathologiques dans les solutions classiques » et on ne l'associe pas aussi directement avec le noyau, il arrive après un long essoufflement pour ainsi dire et l'effet est moins incisif. Néanmoins, les deux possibilités sont acceptables.

Ce qui est un problème, à mon avis, c'est la virgule ; la signification n'est pas la même si les virgules manquent de part et d'autre de la relative; les [explications de la BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4904) à ce sujet (et ses exemples)  devraient être sérieusement assimilées de sorte à pouvoir les appliquer et à être capable de communiquer au lecteur connaissant la langue la notion exacte correspondant à la réalité, cela parce que celui-ci est sûr d'interpréter les virgules. Je vais essayer de donner un exemple avec des phrases courtes.

- Le lion qui s'est enfuit du cirque hier est un animal entièrement sauvage ; le lion dont je parle a un dompteur, c'est un autre lion celui-là, il s'est enfui il y a une semaine.

*La relative sans virgule sert à **déterminer** : c'est de ce lion dont on parle, celui qui s'est enfui du cirque hier.*

- Le lion, qui s'est enfuit du cirque hier, est un animal entièrement sauvage.

*La relative avec virgule sert à décrire, a **donner des explications** en plus ; le lion en liberté est un est un animal entièrement sauvage et **précisément** il s'est échappé  hier.*